# Reading compressed file line by line

Tags: python, file-io

This is my code:

```
    f = gzip.open('nome_file.gz','r')

    line = f.readline()

    for line in f:
            line = f.readline()
            line = line.strip('\n')
            if not line: break
            elements = line.split(" ")
            print elements[0]," ",elements[1]," ",elements[44]," ",elements[45]

    f.close()
```

I really don't know why just one line over two is read.

Answer (score 4):

`for line in f:` reads a line. The next line `line = f.readline()` reads the next line and stores it in the same variable.

You read every line, but skip every second one.

Simply dropping `line = f.readline()` should solve the problem.

Comment: Moreover, in the default file object implementation, `.readline()` and `next(f)` use *different* buffers and you cannot mix the two.

Comment: "-.- Thank you!
I have also another problem, how can I skip the first line? Because in this way (f.readline(0)) it doesn't work.

Comment: You can flag the question as solved, by clicking on the "V" below the answer-score.

Comment: @MartijnPieters can you explain a little more; I don't understand what you mean by *you cannot mix the two*.